# Android CollapsingToolbarLayout without Toolbar to stop at a certain point and not completely close

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I understand that a toolbar is needed so that the CollapsingToolbarLayout does not completely close when you scroll: eg:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIxrx.jpg

I'm trying to figure out if I can get away with the CollapsingToolbarLayout without a Toolbar in it and still won't completely close?

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/annonce.main.coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            app:title="Paky youuu"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="94dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:text="Nooo, don't close!"
                    android:background="@null"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    style="@style/ToolBarWithNavigationBack"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_anchor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
                android:lineSpacingExtra="6dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/vector_ic_alarm_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/linear_anchor"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here's my version:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnMrb.png

On this one, instead of it scrolling up to completely hide it, I want it to stop on this part of the Layout
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjE5E.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkHEY.png

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598313/stop-scroll-on-collapsingtoolbarlayout-so-it-doesnt-completely-collapse

Comment: I do not toolbar as a child AppBarLayout, height after collapse depends on height of toolbar

Answer (score 6):

Set minHeight to CollapsingToolbarLayout and you are done.